# Manage a class with too many instances in a table Django

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django, model

I'm new in Django development and I need your help, please. I have a list of 44.000 rows of products (instances of *product* class).I displayed these products in a table using jquery, but it takes so much time to display them. So I would like to know if there is a way to manage a class with too many instances in a table

This is my product class in models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
   STOCK_STATE = (
       ("Vide", "Vide"),
       ("Faible", "Faible"),
       ("Moyen", "Moyen"),
       ("Satisfaisant", "Satisfaisant"),
       ("Plain", "Plain"),
   )
   product_name = models.CharField(
       max_length=60, null=False, blank=False,)
   image_product = models.ImageField(
       upload_to=upload_location_image, null=False, blank=False)
   last_update = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False)
   price = models.FloatField(null=False, blank=False)
   num_art = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
   stock_state = models.CharField(
       max_length=60, null=False, choices=STOCK_STATE)
   #aisle = models.ManyToManyField(Aisle)
   product_group_code = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
   product_group_name = models.CharField(
       max_length=60, null=False, blank=False)
   product_subgroup_code = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
   product_subgroup_name = models.CharField(
       max_length=60, null=False, blank=False)
 
   def __str__(self):
       return self.product_name
```

this is my views.py

```
def consult_product_view(request, pk ):
    product= Product.objects.get(id=pk)
    anomalies_per_product = product.anomalie_set.all()
    

    context = { 'product': product, 'anomalies_per_product': anomalies_per_product}
    return render(request, 'anomalie/consult_product.html', context)
```

and this is my table.html

```js
<script>
   $('#mydatatable').DataTable({
       pagingType: 'full_numbers',
 
   });
 
</script>
```

```html
<div class="container mb-5 mt-3">
                       <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width: 100%" id="mydatatable">
                          
                           <thead>
 
                               <tr>
                                   <th>Image produit</th>
                                   <th>Nom du produit</th>
                                   <th>Num_art</th>
                                  
 
                               </tr>
                           </thead>
 
 
 
                           <tbody>
                               {% for product in product_list %}
                               <tr>
                                   <td>
                                       <a href="{% url 'consult_product_view' product.id %}">
                                           {% if product.image_product != 'anomalie/0.jpg' %}
                                           <img class="img-responsive image-rezise check" src="{{product.image_product.url}}">
                                           {% else  %}
                                           <img class="img-responsive image-rezise check" src="{% static 'images/unknown_anomalie.png' %}">
                                           {% endif %}
                                       </a>
                                   </td>
                                   <td>{{product.product_name}}</td>
                                   <td>{{product.num_art}}</td>
                               </tr>
                               {% endfor %}
 
                           </tbody>
                           <tfoot>
 
 
 
                           </tfoot>
 
 
                       </table>
                   </div>
```

I'll really appreciate your help!

Comment: do you plan on showing the 44000 rows all at one or use pagination?

Comment: Hi! @Aerials , thanks for your answer. I'm using pagination with the help of Jquery table, but is still very slow to show all the elements.

Comment: use server side pagination! not client side i.e jQuery. you are sending list of 44K entries at once to client, it must be slow.